BFF Implementation: unable to authenticate upon redirection to my React application from asp.net identity server
I am currently trying to create an identity server that only uses external provider (Google) for its authentication, I used React for the login UI that will pop-up once the user logs in and get redirected to my bff application.
PROBLEM:
There was no error, but after redirecting the web-client which is also made from react the application is unable to detect the authenticated user. I am unsure what is wrong if there was no error then what seems to be the issue?
Below is the React.BFF.UI that triggers the Google backend
I am using @axa-fr/react-oidc for handling the openid in my webclient.

This will get triggered when the user clicks the google login button

 const handleSubmitGoogle = async () => {
    window.location.href = `/auth/google?returnUrl=http://localhost:5173/Login`;

  }


builder configuration in my asp.net application

        builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityConfig.IdentityResources)
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(IdentityConfig.ApiScopes)
            .AddInMemoryClients(IdentityConfig.Clients)
            .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users);

        builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
           .AddCookie("google-auth", options =>
           {
               options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true; // Makes the cookie inaccessible to client-side scripts
               options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always; // Ensures the cookie is only sent over HTTPS
               options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60); // Sets the cookie expiration time
                                                                  // Additional configuration...                                                                   
           })
           .AddOpenIdConnect("Google", "Sign-in with Google", options =>
           {
               options.SignInScheme = "google-auth";

               options.Authority = "https://accounts.google.com/";
               options.ClientId = "";
               options.ClientSecret = "";

               options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
               options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
               options.SaveTokens = true;

               options.CallbackPath = "/signin-google";
               options.Scope.Add("openid"); // Required for an id_token
               options.Scope.Add("profile"); // Optional, to include user profile information
               options.Scope.Add("email"); // Already included for email claim
               options.ResponseType = "code"; // Use "code" for Authorization Code flow
           });


Lastly the callback method

    public static async Task<IResult> GoogleLoginCallBack(HttpContext httpContext, IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction, IEventService events)
    {
        // Attempt to authenticate using the external cookie scheme
        var result = await httpContext.AuthenticateAsync("google-auth");
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            // Log the error and handle the failure case appropriately
            // Consider returning a user-friendly error message or redirecting to an error page
            return Results.Problem("External authentication error.");
        }

        // Ensure we have an authenticated principal
        if (result.Principal == null)
        {
            return Results.Problem("External authentication produced a null principal.");
        }

        var externalUser = result.Principal;

        // Prepare for creating a local user session
        var additionalLocalClaims = new List<Claim>();
        var localSignInProps = new AuthenticationProperties();
        CaptureExternalLoginContext(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);

        // Extract the user identifier from the external claims
        var userIdClaim = externalUser.FindFirst(JwtClaimTypes.Subject) ??
                          externalUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        if (userIdClaim == null)
        {
            return Results.Problem("Unknown user identifier.");
        }

        // Extract the provider information
        if (!result.Properties.Items.TryGetValue("scheme", out var scheme))
        {
            return Results.Problem("Provider scheme not found.");
        }

        var provider = scheme;
        // Extract additional user information
        var name = externalUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value ?? "Unknown";
        var subjId = userIdClaim.Value;

        // Create a new IdentityServerUser
        var issuer = new IdentityServerUser(subjId)
        {
            DisplayName = name,
            IdentityProvider = provider,
            AdditionalClaims = additionalLocalClaims,
        };       

        // Sign in the user and clear the external cookie
        await httpContext.SignInAsync(issuer, localSignInProps);

        await httpContext.SignOutAsync("google-auth");

        // Redirect the user to the return URL or a default route
        var returnUrl = result.Properties.Items.TryGetValue("returnUrl", out var url) ? url : "~/";


        var context = await interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);

        if (context != null)
        {

        }

        return Results.Redirect(returnUrl);
    }


I am greatly confuse on what is happening and I am losing hope, I am not sure what is wrong.
I tried the following approaches:

read articles from medium regarding bff approach, please see one of them below

Identity: Google Authentication with React and Asp.NET Identity


watch youtube videos regarding react and bff implementation:

Basics Part 2b: The "external authentication callback" Pattern
Basics Part 2a: Adding external Authentication to your ASP.NET Core Application


referred to github for projects related to bff and react:

adding-a-react-18-user-interface-to-identityserver-6



